# regexp_replace to replace comma from numbers

Tags: regex, replace

I have a need where i want to replace the comma if it is part of Amount in a string and keep the rest of the characters as it is.

Before: 'AAAA, **095,3 USD**, ALL IS good ,5324, agx3, xxyy 24 yz'
After:  'AAAA, **0953 USD**, ALL IS good ,5324, agx3, xxyy 24 yz'

the commas that act as separator between string need to be kept and can be replaced with something for easier to identify. (I used pipe to be kept as separator)

I tried below but need recommendation to correct it:

```
select regexp_replace('AAAA, **0953 USD**, ALL IS good ,5324, agx3, xxyy 24 yz','[^a-zA-Z0-9]+','|');
```

result

```
AAAA|0953|USD|ALL|IS|good|5324|agx3|xxyy|24|yz
```

Need:

```
AAAA|0953 USD|ALL IS good|5324|agx3|xxyy 24|yz
```

Comment: Is a comma _always_ part of the Amount, or might it be the case that the comma is absent? (I noticed it is absent in your example.)

Comment: yes in cases if it is 3 digit it is missing e.g. 900 usd there is no comma, however anything more than 4 digit has comma e.g. 12,456 usd OR 987,888 USD .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [Oracle's syntax for REGEXP_REPLACE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions130.htm) and some testing [here](https://regex101.com/), I think this might do what you want:

```
REGEXP_REPLACE( 'AAAA, 095,3 USD, ALL IS good ,5324, agx3, xxyy 24 yz',
                '([0-9]+),([0-9]+) USD',
                '\1\2 USD' )
```

OP indicated that database is Impala. Per OP's discovery, the correct syntax is:

```
REGEXP_REPLACE( 'AAAA, 095,3 USD, ALL IS good ,5324, agx3, xxyy 24 yz',
                '([0-9]+),([0-9]+) USD',
                '\\1\\2 USD' )
```

See comments below for context.

Comment: AAAA, 12USD, ALL IS good ,5324, agx3, xxyy 24 yz  (thank you however this one has replaced the 095,3 with 12 , is there a way to keep it like 0953 )?? thank you

Comment: That expression should have done that. Apparently REGEXP_REPLACE doesn't work as advertised. I don't have a way of testing this. My apologies.

Comment: You are using Oracle, right? I tested this at SQLFiddle.com and it works fine for Oracle 11g R2. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6206dc/5

Comment: Thank you stonegiant, i am using cloudera.hue and not oracle. maybe impala has some restriction or must have different syntax because you are right, the sytax you gave works perfectly fine in SQLfiddle.

Comment: select REGEXP_REPLACE( 'AAAA, 095,3 USD, ALL IS good ,5324, agx3, xxyy 24 yz', '([0-9]+),([0-9]+) ','\\1\\2 ' );  this got it working. just realized that Imapala uses extra \ to get it to working.  Thank you

Comment: Glad you got it working. Usually a good idea to state the tools you're using when you ask your question. I've updated your question, tagging it with Impala. And, just to be tidy, I've updated my answer with your discovery. -- And just now saw that you added your own answer. Oh well. There it is anyway. ;-) Nicely done.

Answer (score 0):

If lookarounds are supported, this will work:

```
(?<=\d),(?=\d)
```

Answer (score 0):

select REGEXP_REPLACE( 'AAAA, 095,3 USD, ALL IS good ,5324, agx3, xxyy 24 yz', '([0-9]+),([0-9]+) ','\1\2 ' );  this got it working. just realized that Imapala uses extra \ to get it to working.  Thanks StoneGiant